Flink throws java.io.EOFException: Can't collect further: memorySource depleted exception
I have a flink batch mode application with rocksdb state backend, that reads millions of records. The application then partitions the records using keyBy and then sends it to a sink. During kryo serialization (registered a custom serializer) for keyBy, flink throws the below exception:
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can't collect further: memorySource depleted
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.disk.SimpleCollectingOutputView.nextSegment(SimpleCollectingOutputView.java:76)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.AbstractPagedOutputView.advance(AbstractPagedOutputView.java:139)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.AbstractPagedOutputView.write(AbstractPagedOutputView.java:205)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.DataOutputViewStream.write(DataOutputViewStream.java:42)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.flush(Output.java:163)
    ... 26 more


    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:663)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.serialize(KryoSerializer.java:364)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.sort.KeyAndValueSerializer.serialize(KeyAndValueSerializer.java:109)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.sort.KeyAndValueSerializer.serialize(KeyAndValueSerializer.java:44)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.sort.NormalizedKeySorter.write(NormalizedKeySorter.java:297)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.sort.SorterInputGateway.writeRecord(SorterInputGateway.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.sort.ExternalSorterBuilder$1.writeRecord(ExternalSorterBuilder.java:199)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.sort.SortingDataInput$ForwardingDataOutput.emitRecord(SortingDataInput.java:172)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.processElement(AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.java:134)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.emitNext(AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.java:105)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.sort.SortingDataInput.emitNext(SortingDataInput.java:193)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:65)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:542)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:231)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:831)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:780)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:935)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:914)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:728)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:550)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

I allocated enough memory to heap and managed memory and I see that the error occurs while kryo serialization after keyBy operator when data is being passed on to the sink operation. Is there any flink configuration that needs to be adjusted to allocate enough memory to fix this issue?
